# Post multiple lines with PHP

Tags: php

When someone presses the submit button a line is added with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form method ="POST" action="" name ="formpje">

        A line<input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
    </form>

<?php
$post = $_POST['name'];
echo $post;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:

[image]
When i add a new line the current one gets changed to the newest one. I want it to stay as i add a new one. 
Heres what it would look like:

[image]

Comment: Then you have to store that information somewhere and retrieve it when writing to the page.  Session state, a database, a file, etc.

Comment: You need to save the "old" lines and display them after each submit. Do you want to only for the user who entered the line or for all users? Read about sessions (for user specific) or using databases (mysql/sqlite) if you need it for all users.

Comment: When you click submit, you refresh the page ! so you lose last value ! if you want have last value, you should set cookie or session or hidden inputs or save those values somewhere to recover after refresh ! or to be a level up and use Ajax call with jQuery !

Comment: use a session or a tmp cookie, save it the values, and print it as a array, or  as it says @Soheyl use ajax, but you can also implement web sockets.

Comment: Sidenote: You're getting undefined index notices as soon as that file is loaded, but you're not checking for errors and may continue to make your error log file grow as it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, each time you submit the form it will place the name into a session and print it out bellow.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) )
    {  
        $_SESSION[ 'submissions' ][] = $_POST[ 'name' ]; 
    } 
?>
<form method ="POST" action="" name ="formpje">
    A line<input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
</form>

<?php
    foreach( $_SESSION[ 'submissions'] as $line )
    {
        echo $line."\n";  <------ May need to replace this with "<br>" instead of "\n" for the html.
    }
?>
```